# A normal riddle

Tags: riddle

> You read me a beat and a rhyme
>
> In fourths but my total is five.
>
> I don't make a sound,
>
> But you read what you've found
>
> Is nonsense or truth- What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> a limerick

Because

> The question is in the form of a limerick, and describes a limerick.